# Benefits of using an External A/D converter with ATmega128

Tags: adc, atmega, expander

I am new to electronics and working on my first project.  Can someone explain why you would use an external A/D converter instead of the on board one?

According to Mplabs the ATmega128 has a  8-channel 10-bit A/D converter? is it just less accurate?

Comment: There isn't an on-board DAC.  Do you mean on-board A/D converter?

Comment: Yes sorry A/D converter

Comment: External converters may be faster and/or less noisy. Sometimes you don't wanna have the MHz noise from the CPU on the same chip.

Comment: In short.  (1) you can get an external A/D that's better (in one way or another) than the built-in one.  (2) You run out of A/D inputs on the microcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would typically come down to some aspect of performance. If you want 12, 16 or even 20 real bits of result your 10-bit ADC will be woefully inadequate.

In some cases it might be functionality- reference range, or differential input, or maybe an on-board PGA (programmable gain amplifier) or current sources.

Probably conversion speed is not going to be a reason because the AVR is not all that fast, but you might want a large analog bandwidth for undersampling an RF signal.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I want to measure a voltage between -0.3 and 0.3 once every second.  Would you suggest an internal or external ADC?

Comment: I can amplify that to -3 +3 if it is going to benefit me.

Comment: Certainly. The choice depends on how accurately you need to measure it. The range is not a deciding factor, but you'll need some signal conditioning to use the internal ADC (maybe an op-amp and a few resistors, possibly an external reference).

Comment: You should amplify it, but you *need* to level shift it so that it is in the range 0..Vref.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you need more resolution you might need an outrigger.

But my answer is that the only reason I have used external ADCs communicating to the processor is to exceed the number of analog ports offered on the unit itself.

If your external ADC communicated back to the mothership by the use of digital pins then you will need to get one that communicates by other means such I2C.

None of that is difficult.

I'll add one more reason:  If your ADCs need to be some distance then there are other  options such as the Mayhew I2C&Power units that would allow an I2C device to be up to 300 feet away.  I use it and it works, but you likely do not want to start with that complexity.  The power portion is nontrivial.

But if your unit has enough ADC ports by itself, and they have enough resolution, then begin your work using just the ATmega128 all by itself.  And then only when you realize it doesn't have the features you need (resolution, # of inputs, distance) would you want to look into external ADC units.